# Is it possible to fetch all the regions an user can visit in a given travel time in Bing locations api

Tags: bing-maps

Is is possible to fetch / mark all the regions the user can cover from the current location given the travel time using bing maps api

like this - [https://app.traveltime.com/][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking about the isochrone API:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/routes/calculate-an-isochrone#:~:text=The%20Bing%20Maps%20Isochrone%20API%20provides%20time-specific%2C%20isoline,designated%20starting%20point%20within%20a%20set%20time%20period](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/routes/calculate-an-isochrone#:%7E:text=The%20Bing%20Maps%20Isochrone%20API%20provides%20time-specific%2C%20isoline,designated%20starting%20point%20within%20a%20set%20time%20period).